# Passing through values (inherit) in combined transform in CSS animation keyframes?

Tags: css, animation, transform

The goal result is an animation where the rectangle 3d-flips 180 degrees on X-axis while subtly zooming in from the back.

This is what I have so far:

```
@keyframes zoomFlipIn {
  0% { 
    transform: perspective(600px) translateZ(-100px) rotateX(-180deg);
  }

  50% {
    transform: perspective(600px) translateZ(-50px) rotateX(-90deg);
  }

  75% {
    transform: perspective(600px) translateZ(-25px) rotateX(-45deg);
  }

  100% { 
    transform: perspective(600px) translateZ(0) rotateX(0deg);
  }
}
```

Working example: http://codepen.io/zvuc/pen/wBJBXK

So I have `perspective` first to set the separate 3d environment for the animating element, then `translateZ` which moves the box back and forth, then `rotateX` that flips it in x-axis.

I've put it in a picture:

#### Keyframes with all intermediate values set manually:

[image: Figure 01]

Which works fine, but now I have a question, is there a way to omit a single `transform` property value from an inbetween keyframe?

#### Keyframes with some intermediate values omitted:

[image]

To put it in code, it would be:

```
@keyframes zoomFlipIn {
  0% { 
    transform: perspective(600px) translateZ(-100px) rotateX(-180deg);
  }

  50% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(-90deg);
  }

  75% {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateX(-45deg);
  }

  100% { 
    transform: perspective(600px) translateZ(0) rotateX(0deg);
  }
}
```

As far as I know animation will work properly only when the keyframes have matching properties in all the steps, so obviously this will not animate as intended because the 2 inbetween steps are missing the `translateZ` functions. (In this example the keyframes and rotation steps are equally stepped to keep things simple, so you could just get rid of the `25%` and `75%` keyframes and get the same result in this specific case, but let's take that out of consideration for now)

And indeed when I test the above code, animation doesn't work out correctly.

So I came to think, if there is an `inherit` value for transform functions I can use to pass through values from the previous keyframe, so I tried it out:

**Method #01:**

```
@keyframes zoomFlipIn {
  0% { 
    transform: perspective(600px) translateZ(-100px) rotateX(-180deg);
  }

  50% {
    transform: perspective(600px) translateZ(inherit) rotateX(-90deg);
  }

  75% {
    transform: perspective(600px) translateZ(inherit) rotateX(-45deg);
  }

  100% { 
    transform: perspective(600px) translateZ(0) rotateX(0deg);
  }
}
```

**Method #02:**

```
@keyframes zoomFlipIn {
  0% { 
    transform: perspective(600px) translateZ(-100px) rotateX(-180deg);
  }

  50% {
    transform: perspective(600px) translateZ() rotateX(-90deg);
  }

  75% {
    transform: perspective(600px) translateZ() rotateX(-45deg);
  }

  100% { 
    transform: perspective(600px) translateZ(0) rotateX(0deg);
  }
}
```

Or even,
**Method #03:**

```
@keyframes zoomFlipIn {
  0% { 
    transform: perspective(600px) translateZ(-100px) rotateX(-180deg);
  }

  50% {
    transform: perspective(600px) translateZ rotateX(-90deg);
  }

  75% {
    transform: perspective(600px) translateZ rotateX(-45deg);
  }

  100% { 
    transform: perspective(600px) translateZ(0) rotateX(0deg);
  }
}
```

I am pretty sure that this wouldn't be valid syntax, because I never heard of such a notation. But interestingly, all three methods displayed the animation as intended, transitioning from -100px to -0px smoothly for duration of the whole animation timeline. Just the same as where the `-50px` and `-25px` values were manually entered.

Checked in latest Chrome and Firefox and both worked fine.

Well if it works fine, I could just go ahead and use it, but I wanted to check if this was a behavior by a bug(whichever way the browser interprets the syntax) and/or the actual W3C documentation explains of such a notation. I searched all around but could not find an example where it uses combined transform notations and keyframe animations at the same time.

Any ideas on this issue?